# Yocto: Is there a way to remove items of SRC_URI in local.conf?

Tags: overriding, yocto

We are using custom kernel, so I override variables defined in linux-imx_xxx.bb:

```
KERNEL_SRC_pn-linux-imx = "our_url"
SRCBRANCH_pn-linux-imx = "our_branch"
SRCREV_pn-linux-imx = "${AUTOREV}"
```

It works. But many patch files added in linux-imx_xxx.bb and out custom kernel have patched.

So I want to just remove patch files in local.conf, and not touch any .bb files defined in official meta-fsl-* layers.

```
SRC_URI_remove_pn-linux-imx = " file://*.patch"
```

But this doesn't work. So is there a way to do this in local.conf?

BTW I know the .bbappend should works, but again, I don't want change any meta-fsl-* layers.

Comment: So you don't want to add any patch files from meta-fsl*/linux-imx_xxx.bb into your kernel. But you need only your custom patches applied?

Comment: @Parthiban, No, we have no any patch now. Our kernel base was generated  from "devtool  modify linux-imx" command, it's patched. So we don't need any patch to apply now.

Comment: Then you need to replace the whole `SRC_URI` variable value in `.bbappend` / `local.conf` of your recipe i.e. you should not use `SRC_URI +=`.

Comment: As mentioned in the below answer by Ross Burton, you can't use wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a wildcard because _remove is literal string removal.  Spell out the files you want to remove, and you'll be fine.

However if you're using a custom kernel then just write a new recipe for it, no point taking linux-imx and editing it from local.conf.

Comment: I removed wildcard and use full uri, it works now. Thanks! 
Our custom kernel is based on linux-imx, that's why I editing it from local.conf